# How Does the Following Definition of the Axiom of Choise Entail that Elements Are Simultaneously Chosen from an Infinite Collection of Nonempty Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

The following excerpt is from Ethan Bloch, [Proofs and Fundamentals: A First Course in Abstract Mathematics](https://books.google.it/books?id=QJ_537n8zKYC&printsec=frontcover) (2nd ed, 2011 : page 121) and concerns one of the motivations for introducing the axiom of choice (AC). Initially, the author explains that for a finite collection $\Gamma$ of nonempty finite sets $\Gamma_i$, we can choose a single element $\gamma \in \Gamma_i$  sequentially for all $i \in I$ where $I$ is an indexing set, and eventually we will have a new set $\Lambda$ which contains those elements $\gamma$ in a finite number of steps. The problem of choosing a single element sequentially arises when the collection is infinitely large:

> If we want to choose one element from each set in an infinite family of nonempty sets, we need to make the choices simultaneously. Such a simultaneous choice is not something we could physically do, and the ability to do so mathematically does not follow from the [ZF] axioms of set theory. Therefore, we need an additional axiom to guarantee our ability to make such choices, and that axiom is the Axiom of Choice

Since the discussion of AC was introduced prior to the concept of a function, the author defines AC in terms of sets:

> Let $x$ be a set. Suppose that if $y,w \in x$, then $y \neq \varnothing$ and $y  \cap w = \varnothing$. Then there is a set $z$ such that if $y \in x$, then $y \cap z$ contains a single element.

Okay, now that I have laid the foundation, here is my question: What in the above definition entails that the elements are simultaneously chosen when $x$ is an infinite collection of nonempty sets?

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate. Have you tried looking for previously asked questions?

Comment: (There might be better duplicates, but this is the first one that came up. In the question "choice set"is exactly $z$ as in the definition of AC you have.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I don't see how your answer to the post that you referenced me to answers my question as to how elements are **simultaneously** chosen from an infinite collection of nonempty sets. I don't see how the mathematics that you've written in your answer in the referenced post answers my question.

Comment: Choosing "simultaneously" means to have a function $f$ which "chooses" an element from each set, namely $f(x)\in x$. As for something we can "physically do", show me how we can physically choose an element from $2^{2^{2^{32}}}$ sets, in fact show me that many sets. In fact show me *a* set physically. In either case, either your question is about terminology, what does it mean to choose elements, in which case you should phrase it like that; or it is about the mathematics behind it, in which case the duplicate answers this quite well.

Comment: @AsafKaragila The "physically" part of the author's excerpt has nothing to do with my question, so you wanting me to show a physical set is unnecessary. Calm down. I just wanted to know how the definition of AC as defined in the second excerpt implied that elements are chosen at the same time rather than sequentially.

Comment: I think that the use of the locution "physically do" by the Author (see Bloch, page 121) is a "bad choice". The sense is : "we cannot perform it in a finite number of steps" (see some lines before). A sequential process will never be concluded with an infinite set $X$; thus, the need of an axiom that licences us to assert that the "result" $Z$ of the "selection process" will be completed "by fiat".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I understand that, but my real issue is where in the definition of AC enables us to see that the elements are being chosen simultaneously as opposed to sequentially.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Also, let's ignore the "physical" part of the excerpt: It was contained in the excerpt I presented, and I didn't realize it was going to be a concentrated issue. If I did know that was going to be a new problem, I would have omitted it. I really just want to know how the given definition of AC implies that the elements of $x$ where $x$ is an infinite set are simultaneously chosen as opposed to sequentially chosen to be elements in $z$. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: So your question is about the meaning of the phrase "choice function". Not about the mathematics.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, because, for some reason, I always thought of $b = f(a)$ where $f: A \rightarrow B$ mapped $f(a)$ to each $b$ to be a sequential process, so when the author said, essentially, "Well, if $A$ is infinite, you can't do that. Instead, here's the definition of AC that says the choice function simultaneously maps the elements," but I don't see how the definition implies that.

Comment: See the initial discussion of [Axiom of Choice](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/axiom-choice/index.html), in particular the formulation **AC1**: any collection of nonempty sets has a choice function, and [footnote 4](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/axiom-choice/notes.html#4) with the well-knowm example by Russell.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that the reopening votes are justified. The OP has asked this question as intended (and it got answered). If this were to be reopened, then it should then be closed as a duplicate of the new question.

Comment: But, frankly speaking, I think that also the dichotomy sequntially/ simultaneously is out of place here; in math there is no "time". It seems that the real "motivation" for the choice axiom is that provided by Russell: for a colllection $X$ of pair of shoes we can have a "choice rule" : pick up the left (or right) and we have defined the function producing the set $Z$. 1/2

Comment: The above rule "works" also in an infinite case. For a collection of socks, if it is *finite*, we can imagine to choose the members of $Z$ one-by-one (pointing at the elements with a finger) and thus we can again assume that we have defined a choice function. But, for an infinite collection of pair of socks we clearly have no way to "compress" in a finite descrivable rule or function the infinite number of choices needed to "collect" $Z$. Thus, the need for the Axiom... 2/2